# Dual Boot Partitions__Ubuntu running out of space

Tags: partitioning

My computer has an unallocated free space of 3.69 GB according to Gparted in Ubuntu. I want to add that unallocated space of 3.69 Gb to the Ubuntu Partition. My problem is that when I type the command line in the terminal in Ubuntu I get dev/sda 5 to 8 with Linux. To which one do I add this unallocated free space ??

Please check the graphics if that helps.

Comment: You've asked this question twice. Please delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you want the extra space on your file system. If you type 'mount' in a terminal, it will give you a list of partitions that are mounted at that time. You will most likely want to add the free space to the partition specified mounted as root, /. You could also add it to /home /var, /etc depending on your set up.